# Is there an API for sharing task progress in Google Cloud Tasks?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

Suppose we have a web-service, that does some time-consuming processing of a file submitted by user. Operations on the file are not running inside the HTTP(s) request handler, as it really affects user experience. Instead, once the user submits the file, a new Google Cloud Task's task gets created and posted to the HTTP(s) endpoint which handles the file processing.

The task runs pretty long, so the user should be updated with the progress to have a better  waiting experience. As a beginner user of GCP, I have the following questions.

Is there an API in Google Cloud Tasks to achieve that? For example, some API that allows to set custom metadata on a task object to retrieve it from the other side later.

If not, what are the best practices of storing the progress information of the Google Cloud Task's task?  What services are the best to use in this case? 
The simplest idea is just to store the progress information using plain text files on the Google Storage bucket.

Assume there's a different HTTP(s) handler that receives the polling requests and must return current task progress. The progress is determined by the file-processing code.

Comment: Aren't the files being processed asynchronously? Like once the file is uploaded (to a server??) and the Cloud Task is added, user must be notified in a way? Also, I am not sure how a task's progress is calculated at first place but maybe you can keep updating the progress in Firebase Realtime Database and client can listen to it (unless you want to implement your own service for sockets). Might be better to have some more context on whats happening.